# Angular Application files being cached by the browser

Tags: angular, iis, browser, angular5

I have got an issue with an Angular 5 application. For some weird reason the browser does not fetch the new version of the files even though the files have been hashed automatically by default by the webpack configuration.

The following pictures depicts the issue:

This is the chrome console showing the files used by the app, even when refreshing the page multiple times:

[image]

The following picture shows the files on the server:

[image]

As you can see my main.{hash}.bundle.js file is different from the one the browser has. How is that possible that the browser does NOT identify there are new files with a different hash names on the server? Any idea what the problem is? I would appreciate any help .

Comment: which web server did you used?

Comment: @miladfm We are using IIS

Comment: Does it happen as well after deleting cache?

Comment: @AlexanderMeise , No it does not, If works if i delete the browser cache.

Comment: Your browser is probably using a cached index.html, which still refers to the old hash name for main.bundle ("1fa233..."), which the browser can still retrieve from its cache.

Comment: any ideas? we just had the same issue during deploy

Comment: seems to be a very painful issue. Can we do something about it?